# Getting data into MySQL from remote client without using Apache/PHP

Tags: mysql

I have a client microprocessor which will periodically send data via the Internet to a Linux server to be inserted into a MySQL table.

One option is to have the microprocessor send a HTTP POST request to the server, have Apache receive the request, and have PHP process the data and insert it into the database.  Apache and PHP will already be on the server, so maybe this is the right way to do it, but would like to know if there are other options.

Without using Apache and PHP to receive the data and insert it into the database, are there other options?  I recognize that maybe the microprocessor will have to send something other than a HTTP POST request.

Comment: Another option is to expose the mysql server to the internet and allow your microprocessor to directly connect to the mysql instance and directly insert data.

Comment: Could the connection be encrypted using something equivalent to SSL?  The microprocessor will also need to send some sort of username/password.  The database will store data from different microprocessors, and will need to ensure that incoming data is verified.  Can this be doing directly with MySQL?  I was also thinking that maybe there is some other application lighter weight than PHP/Apache that could do this.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ssl-connections.html

Comment: It can be done. Whether or not it should be done depends on whether you prefer application logic to exist centrally on your server or whether it is preferrable to have each microprocessor decide how to use mysql.

Comment: @hofan41  Thanks, that makes sense, and gives me something to think about.